# Parse du result using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, disk-usage, json

Hello i am trying to parse the result of du command but i don't know how to do it without looping
i execute the below command

```
du -shm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail
```

my result is a list e.g.:

```
80 /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/USER1/mail 
150 /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/USER2/mail 
220 /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/USER3/mail
```

The above list i want to transform it to json object with the below:

```json
{USER1: 80, USER2:150, USER3:220 }
```

or at least to have something:

```json
80 USER1
150 USER2
220 USER3
```

I tried with `sed -e` but without success, any ideas?

Comment: Show what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
du -shm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail | awk -F '[ /]' '{ print $1, $7 }'
```

With the input from `du` in the format that you give, this would produce

```
80 USER1
150 USER2
220 USER3
```

The `awk` program simply picks out the appropriate fields from the output of `du`. It interprets each line as fields delimited by either spaces or slashes.

`awk -F '[ /]' '{ print $1, $(NF - 1) }'` would also work.

To get this into JSON, using `jq`:

```
du -shm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail |
awk -F '[ /]' '{ print $1, $7 }' |
jq -sR 'split("\n")[0:-1] | map(split(" ")) | map({(.[1]):.[0]}) | add'
```

This would produce

```
{
  "USER1": "80",
  "USER2": "150",
  "USER3": "220"
}
```

---

The `jq` expression first splits the input into separate array elements (one per line of input), and then splits these again on spaces into subarrays.  At this point we have

```
[
  [
    "80",
    "USER1"
  ],
  [
    "150",
    "USER2"
  ],
  [
    "220",
    "USER3"
  ]
]
```

After that, objects are created with the second element in each subarray as the key and the first as the value:

```
[
  {
    "USER1": "80"
  },
  {
    "USER2": "150"
  },
  {
    "USER3": "220"
  }
]
```

The `add` at the end gives us the final result.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
du -sm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail |
  sed 's:/var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/::; s:/mail::'
```

where

- `s:/mail::` will replace `/mail` by nothing

to go to json

```
du -sm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail |
  sed 's:/var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/::; s:/mail::' |
  awk 'BEGIN { sep="{" ;} { printf "%s \"%s\":%s",sep,$2,$1; sep="," } END { printf "}\n"}'
```

Comment: JSON requires keys to be double-quoted strings.  Changing the `printf` statement to `printf "%s \"%s\":%s",sep,$2,$1;` is enough to make this generate valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to convert to 2-column format:

```
$ du -shm | awk -F/ '{print $1" "$(NF - 1)}'
80  USER1
150  USER2
220  USER3
```

For JSON, try:

```
$ du -shm | awk -F/ '{print "\""$(NF - 1)"\":"$1}' | paste -sd, | printf "{$(cat)}" | jq
{
  "USER1": 80,
  "USER2": 150,
  "USER3": 220
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`jq` does pretty well with raw-text, i.e. the `-R` flag, e.g.:

```
du -sm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail |
jq -R '
  split(" ") |
    .[0]                      as $size |  # Remember size 
    .[1] | split("/") | .[-2] as $name |  # Extract username
    { ($name) : ($size) }                 # Compose object
'
```

Gives you:

```json
{
  "USER1": "80"
}
{
  "USER2": "150"
}
{
  "USER3": "220"
}
```

To merge the objects, use a second `jq` invocation:

```
... | jq -s add
```

Output:

```json
{
  "USER1": "80",
  "USER2": "150",
  "USER3": "220"
}
```

Or in compact mode:

```
... | jq -sc add
```

Output:

```json
{"USER1":"80","USER2":"150","USER3":"220"}
```

Comment: Why use a second invocation of `jq` when you could just tack `add` on to the end of the first `jq` pipeline?

Comment: @Kusalananda: it wraps every object then

Comment: Ah, because they are not in an array.

Comment: on this solution i receive the below error
 jq: error (at <stdin>:1): split input and separator must be strings

Comment: @user1521944: are you using jq version1.5?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky to do with `sed`. However, here is a commented suggestion that works with GNU sed:

*parse.sed*

```sed
s|([^ ]+) .*/([^/]+)/.*|  "\2" : \1,|   # Extract size and name in json-format
1h; 1!H                                 # Correctly add them to hold-space
$ {
  z                                     # Clear pattern-space
  s/^/\{/                               # Prepend start-curly-brace
  G                                     # Fetch formatted json from hold-space
  s/,$//                                # Remove last comma
  s/$/\n\}/                             # Append end-curly-brace
  p                                     # Print
}
```

Run it like this:

```
du -shm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail | sed -Enf parse.sed
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
du -shm /var/vmail/mailboxes/domain/*/mail |
sed -Ene 's|([^ ]+) .*/([^/]+)/.*|  "\2" : \1,|;1h;1!H;${z;s/^/\{/;G;s/,$//;s/$/\n\}/;p}'
```

Output in both cases:

```json
{
  "USER1" : 80,
  "USER2" : 150,
  "USER3" : 220
}
```